# Facebook API Insights how to get results conversion?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

How can I get **results** from `Facebook API`insights? I managed to get a list of campaigns / ads, then pull out all the necessary data, but here **results** does not display this field at all. In the ads manager panel there is a column **Results**, how to pull data from this column as on the screen? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PhjHE.png)

UPD: used this method for get reports https://graph.facebook.com/v6.0/act_XXXX/insights?breakdowns=publisher_platform&time_range={"since":"2020-01-01","until":"2020-03-24"}&fields=["adset_name", "objective","impressions","spend","actions"]&access_token=XXXX&level=adset

**objective** field value is different from action value type, how now to understand which to use from **actions**?

Comment: Can you edit your question to either include the method you used, or a code snippet for getting the campaign list? Your approach will determine which appropriate solutions are available. Make sure to remove sensitive information (api keys, credentials, etc)

Comment: @JoshSharkey thanks you, question was updated.